# Formatting text using either linux or python

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I am new to scripting so any help would really go a long way,

It more relates to Cisco routers config files, first format is when you run the command "show running-config", and the second part is when you use command "show running-config formal"

So, I want to convert my config txt file to later format.

I have a file in my linux OS which is indented with following data,

```
control-plane     
 management-plane   
  inband    
   interface all   
    allow xy   
     address  x.x.x.x   
     address  y.y.y.y   

    !   
    allow b   
     address  b.b.b.b   
    !  
   !  
  !
```

and what I want, is to remove its formatting so basically appends sub-sections to parent like this, either using linux commands or script it using python. what you think would be the best approach to do that?

```
control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow xy   
control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow xy address  x.x.x.x   
control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow xy address  y.y.y.y   
control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow b   
control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow b address b.b.b.b
```

Using same concept I want to reformat further in the same file,

```
service sesh instance1
 service-location preferred-active 0/3/CPU0
 service-type nps nps-1
  forced-placement npu 0
  tunnel type gre
   name gre10
   tunnel-destination ipv4 address 209.165.200.225
   ipv4 address 192.0.2.6/24
   remote ipv4 address 192.0.2.5/24
   tunnel-source ipv4 address 209.165.200.226
  !
  package nps-mips64-r2.rpm
  interface ServiceApp1
   remote ipv4 address 209.165.200.227/24
  !
 !
!

template pre-pos
 interface preconfigure POS0/1/0/0
  ipv4 address 10.3.32.154 255.0.0.0 
!
```

I have also attached [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK4sV.jpg), just to give a clearer picture.

Thanks

Sal

Comment: I can't tell if you want to output on "allow" and "address" lines, or lowest-two-levels of the tree, or what.  The approach I'd take is to convert the file to a Python structure (list-of-lists-of-lists... in this case) representing the input as a tree. Then you can work on converting that tree to whatever serialized output format you like.

Comment: @MikeHousky- Hi Mike, so I am not sure if you are familiar with routers, but first one is when you run the command "show running-config", and the second part is when you use command "show running-config formal"

I want to convert my config file to later format.

Comment: Nope...didn't recognize that format.  If this is a one-off, it looks like you have an answer.  My approach would have been much heavier-handed than you really needed.

Comment: @MikeHousky
so I added further input in the main post, would you give some idea of applying list of list/tree to reformat it the way I want in single line?

Comment: Why do you want or need the partial commands `control-plane management-plane inband interface all allow xy` and `… b`?

Comment: I work daily on analyzing log data, once I remove formatting on !  it will make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this could help:

```
file = open('text.txt','r')
allow_indices=[]
exl_indices=[]
content=[]
i = 0
for line in file:
    if 'allow' in line:
        allow_indices.append(i)
    if '!' in line:
        exl_indices.append(i)
    content.append(line)
    i += 1
file = open('text.txt','r')

base=''
formatted=''

for i in range(0,allow_indices[0]):
    base+= content[i]

close_index=0
for i in allow_indices:
    new_base = base+content[i]
    formatted+=new_base.replace('\n','')+'\n'
    for j in range(i+1,exl_indices[close_index]-1):
        formatted+=new_base.replace('\n','')+content[j].replace('\n','')+'\n'
        close_index+=1

print formatted
```

I used the following as content of text.txt file:

```
control-plane
 management-plane
  inband
   interface all
    allow xy
     address x.x.x.x
     address y.y.y.y

    !
    allow b
     address  b.b.b.b
    !
   !
  !
```

And I got the following as result:

```
control-plane      management-plane     inband       interface all       allow xy   
control-plane      management-plane     inband       interface all       allow xy        address x.x.x.x   
control-plane      management-plane     inband       interface all       allow xy        address y.y.y.y   
control-plane      management-plane     inband       interface all       allow b   
control-plane      management-plane     inband       interface all       allow b        address  b.b.b.b
```

Comment: you think there will be more effective way to reformat it?? I updated more text data in my actual post above, which would fail these checks. I am thinking of maybe breaking at ! mark but not successful yet.

Comment: It should work if you add 'tunnel type' and 'package' indices to allow_indices table, can do it by adding this "if 'tunnel type' in line:
        allow_indices.append(i)" just after line 6 and the same for package

Comment: If you do not mind, can you walk me through a little with example, this will help me get going quick.